# How can i Kill app Pedometer with a Service?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I have a samsung gear pro 2 and the pedometer app consumes 50% of the battery.
I would like to create an app or a service that keeps me closed the pedometer, which I do not need.
I can not find anything on the documentation, only for the web (but after 10 minutes it closes), I need it in C ++ because it is the only way to run this control 24/7. Thank you.

Comment: You may write a native service to start and stop sensor 
https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/location-and-sensors/device-sensors 

And using sensor 
https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/how-use-light-sensor-tizen

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply.
I managed to create a service, but I did not find the function to block the acceleration.
What is the name of this function?

Comment: Did you try using sensor.Stop api to stop ? Please check and let me know ....if that doesn't work, i don't know any other way to stop that